# registerReceiver issue with in-app billing messages?

Tags: android

I'm implementing in-app billing support in my application. I just realized that even though the application has been stopped, the standard billing broadcast receiver is still receiving billing messages from the market service. So, instead of declaring my receiver inside the manifest file:

```
    <receiver android:name=".receiver.billing.BillingReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.android.vending.billing.IN_APP_NOTIFY" />
            <action android:name="com.android.vending.billing.RESPONSE_CODE" />
            <action android:name="com.android.vending.billing.PURCHASE_STATE_CHANGED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

I decided to go with the Context.registerReceiver method in order to ensure that my application is actually ready to correctly handle billing messages:

```
    _billingReceiver = new BillingReceiver();
    final IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("com.android.vending.billing.IN_APP_NOTIFY");
    filter.addAction("com.android.vending.billing.RESPONSE_CODE");
    filter.addAction("com.android.vending.billing.PURCHASE_STATE_CHANGED");
    _billingService.registerReceiver(_billingReceiver, filter);
```

The problem now is that BillingReceiver.onReceive is not called anymore. Is there an issue of some kind preventing billing messages to be sent to dynamically registered receivers. I looked through Google/Android's doc and found nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you not want to receive billing messages when the application has been stopped? It means that you could miss important messages from the market about purchases and refunds.

You'll notice that in the dungeons example they have a database that they log all purchase information to. Then their UI uses the database to keep the user informed about the status of their purchase. This is so that if a user went to some other app while their purchase was being processed they could come back and see that the purchase had completed successfully.

Comment: The main reason is that when receiving market messages, my billing service makes requests to a server, and the application is not ready to make those requests until it has been fully initialized, which is a process that typically occurs when the main activity gets created. But I see what you mean: billing messages should be processed ASAP to relieve the market service, otherwise it will have to continue broadcasting the same IN_APP_BILLING notifications. So I will have to move the needed initialization stuff inside my billing service in order to process the billing messages.

Comment: Yeah you really want to be talking to your server from a service linked to the billing receiver anyway. Otherwise you're likely to miss recording legitimate purchases on your server. My implementation puts server access code in the BillingSecurity class. It seems to work ok.